# Firebase API key restrictions issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, api-key

I am using Firebase Authentication and Firebase dynamic links in my android project. I have put restrictions in my API key here
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/
and allowed only android app with the package name and signature i specified. But there are still people able to create accounts using my API key outside my application and using script. I don't know how is this possible. As per firebase docs, it should be restricted to only my app. Is there anything i am missing to prevent people creating accounts through script?

Note: I am just using Firebase authentication, No firestore or Realtime database.